# Statistically testing spatial correlations between two spatial categorical variables in R?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

For example, each Census Tract has two categorical variables derived from two different methods.  I'd like to figure out how similar those two methods are.

The software I will be using is R.

I have tried looking up answers online, but they do not quite answer my question.  The answers online either involve auto-correlation of one variable or testing of spatial correlation between two continuous variables.

Comment: This is the sort of question that requires a half-hour tutorial session with a stats tutor. Do the two categorical variables have the same set of categories? Then could you model if the two categories for a census area agree or differ, in which case you are left with a binary (binomial) model. Then there's the question of what's the model behind all this. Have you tried writing down a model for the joint distribution of categorical responses, given the data?